# Block/Don't allow comments for specific blogs in SharePoint 2013 (on-premise)

Tags: 2013, blog

Our CEO has setup a blog and would like to block/don't allow users to comments on certain blogs.

In other blogs, he would like user to make comments.

Can this be done out of the box?

If not, what is the best way to adress it?

Comment: Alkis, do you mean that your CEO would want to block comments on specific posts in the same Blog or block comments on all posts in a specific Blog? :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you cannot do it directly OOB. So as I see it you have two possibillities.

1. Add a field on the blog list to select if it should be commented. Then add a script on the blogpage to hide the comment webpart
2. Add a field on the blog. Add page without comment webpart. Add calculated column that creates a link to either the one or the other page.. Still this needs a javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer - I wouldn't delete any web parts (the blog functionality is very poorly made even by Msft's low standards and things break!). Instead, HIDE the comments web part in web part properties, and add this styling to the post.aspx page (script editor or cewp will do) to remove the stupidly placed "0 COMMENTS" heading and the comments link:

```
.ms-secondaryCommandLink, .ms-blog-postComments{display:none;}
```

That way, if minds are changed, you can always restore things without pulling your hair out.